# How can I click on specific table row using Geb

Tags: geb

I'm fairly new to Geb and am trying to click on a specific table column/row.

For example I am wanting to locate and click on the link named "Delete" for the row named foo. Of course there is no table id class or name to select from to make this extra challenging. Any help is appreciated

[image: My Table]

==HTML for table==

```
<div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
<table role="grid">
<colgroup>
<thead role="rowgroup">
<tr role="row">
<th id="564a14e5-657d-4dd4-babe-0d13d56fb7d1" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="0" data-title="Criteria Name" rowspan="1" data-field="name" role="columnheader" data-role="columnsorter">
<a class="k-link">Criteria Name</a>
</th>
<th id="4f9e5c37-ac63-4e2b-a4ba-a8c5d3673179" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="1" data-title="Start Date" rowspan="1" data-field="startDateTime" role="columnheader" data-role="columnsorter">
<th id="25ef77e5-6d6e-4376-9bf2-fea1becfabe9" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="2" data-title="End Date" rowspan="1" data-field="endDateTime" role="columnheader" data-role="columnsorter">
<th id="41725a3a-d62e-43e2-ac81-5008da54ca74" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="3" data-title="Location Name(s)" rowspan="1" data-field="locationNames" role="columnheader" data-role="columnsorter">
<th id="7c719826-0c9a-4751-bf64-344e0885e237" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="4" data-title="Classification(s)" rowspan="1" data-field="classifNames" role="columnheader" data-role="columnsorter">
<th id="d7abbc0a-ea63-4b2f-8c79-44ca133d2e85" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="5" data-title="Employee Name(s)" rowspan="1" data-field="empNames" role="columnheader" data-role="columnsorter">
<th id="17a9317e-30f5-4a30-8822-ff3b302e0071" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="6" rowspan="1" role="columnheader"></th>
<th id="c2f499a2-fffa-4994-98f4-833e4d844cfc" class="k-header ng-scope" data-index="7" rowspan="1" role="columnheader"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
<div class="k-grid-content">
<table role="grid">
<colgroup>
<tbody role="rowgroup">
<tr class="ng-scope" role="row" data-uid="dc5a6a0e-7fec-45d7-9978-25e9af65bbd7">
<tr class="k-alt ng-scope" role="row" data-uid="aee1377f-0c41-4e6e-9054-25cbb564cb00">
<td role="gridcell">
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="dataItem.name">Crit_12_30_17</span>
</td>
<td role="gridcell">12/4/2017 12:00 AM</td>
<td role="gridcell">12/29/2017 11:59 PM</td>
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<span>
<a ng-click="selectCriteria($event)" style="cursor: pointer;">Select Criteria</a>
</span>
</td>
<td role="gridcell">
<span>
<a ng-click="deleteCriteria(683)" style="cursor: pointer;">Delete</a>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ng-scope" role="row" data-uid="309c009d-08a8-4a7c-bb2c-fef5a295e72d">
<td role="gridcell">
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="dataItem.name">my_saved_criteria</span>
</td>
<td role="gridcell">7/18/2017 6:32 AM</td>
<td role="gridcell">7/21/2017 6:32 AM</td>
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<span>
<a ng-click="selectCriteria($event)" style="cursor: pointer;">Select Criteria</a>
</span>
</td>
<td role="gridcell">
<span>
<a ng-click="deleteCriteria(729)" style="cursor: pointer;">Delete</a>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="k-alt ng-scope" role="row" data-uid="fabed2df-b5c6-45dd-8595-e411e70c6594">
<td role="gridcell">
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="dataItem.name">foo</span>
</td>
<td role="gridcell">7/18/2017 12:00 AM</td>
<td role="gridcell">7/19/2017 11:59 PM</td>
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<td role="gridcell">
<span>
<a ng-click="selectCriteria($event)" style="cursor: pointer;">Select Criteria</a>
</span>
</td>
<td role="gridcell">
<span>
<a ng-click="deleteCriteria(730)" style="cursor: pointer;">Delete</a>
</span>
 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answer, consider using Module to model your table and moduleList to collect all rows.

```
import geb.Module
import geb.Page

class MyPage extends Page {

    static at = {
        title == "whatever"
    }

    static content = {

        savedCriteriaTable { $(".k-grid-content > table") }
        tableRows { savedCriteriaTable.$('tbody > tr').moduleList(TableRows) }
    }

    static def findAndDeleteRow(String textToFind){

        def row = tableRows.findResult { it.criteriaName == textToFind ? it : null}
        row.deleteLink.click()
    }
}

class TableRows extends Module
{
    static content = {
        cell { $("td") }
        criteriaName { cell[0].text() }
        startDate { cell[1].text() }
        endDate { cell[2].text() }
        locationName { cell[3].text() }
        classifications { cell[4].text() }
        employeeName { cell[5].text() }
        selectCriteriaLink { cell[6].$("a") }
        deleteLink { cell[7].$("a") }
    }
}
```

Calling findAndDeleteRow("Criteria651") for instance should then click the delete link for the corresponding row.

Although i've tried to match the code to your html I've not tested it, guessing you may need to tweak it slightly.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to go about doing what you want, but when dealing with Tables I tend to go with this approach:

It's all about creating a well structured page Object class for this page.

```
class YourPage extends Page{
    static content = {
        //first start by defining the table Navigator (you don't have to use xpath like I did)
        table {$(By.xpath("//table")}
    }

    //next I make a set of Table access methods like so (you may need to adjust for your case, but the idea still remains):

    //grabs a table row based on index
    getRow(int index){
        return table.children().getAt(index)
    }

    //You can do the same thing as above, but based on text instead:
    getRow(String name){
        return table.children().find{ it.text() == name } 
    }

    //next I typically make methods to access a particular column given a row like so:
    getCriteriaName(row){
        return row.children().getAt(0)
    }

    getStartData(row){
        return row.children().getAt(1)
    }

    //following this pattern, to get the delete element of a given row would be:
    getDeleteButton(row){
        return row.children().getAt(7)
    }
}
```

now from your main script if you wanted to click that particular delete button for that particular row you would say this:

```
at YourPage
getDeleteButton(getRow(3)).click()
```

Now I didn't look at your HTML too closely so like I said, you might need to remove Headers before the indices match up, but typically Tables will follow this same pattern, and if you do it this way you can access any element in the table easily.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I am seeing if I can get this to work.

Comment: @DennisFerguson Yeah no problem. if you haven't done so already, check out the [Navigator API](http://gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/navigator/Navigator.html) you can chain the methods that return Navigators together to easily traverse the HTML. Remember that multi Element navigators are iterable as well. Try to utilize the parent/child relationships in the HTML

Comment: Thank you both :)